# A piece of code gets executed only in immediate window in VS 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, immediate-window

I have a line of code behaving weirdly.

```
objectType = ((DependencyObject)obj).GetValue(FrameworkElementExtensions.IdProperty) as string;
```

The above line returns "" when i run the code or even when i debug the code. But when i execute the same statement in the immediate window it returns me the proper string.
I tried executing the statement twice but still it didn't work.

Any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: Can you please paste the code where you are displaying the value...

Comment: @Saad khatri This particular piece of code is inside a 'if' block and this is the only statement inside the block. I execute the statement inside the immediate window at the end of the if block. Does that answer your question?

Comment: That property which i am referring to is an attached property. I suspect there could be some problem with the loading of a dll. But i am not able to figure out which one it is. 
Does this help anyone in answering my question? Have i provided enough information?